# Color detection in opencv

Tags: opencv, colors, detection

I want to detect a specific color say, blue, from a live video stream.
I have written the following code which displays the live video stream and change it into HSV and grayscale. Since I am completely new to opencv I have no idea what to do next.

Can someone complete the code for me to detect a specific color.

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;


int main(){
Mat image;
Mat gray;
Mat hsv;
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("gray", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("hsv", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while (1){
    cap >> image;
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    imshow("window", image);
    imshow("gray", gray);
    imshow("hsv", hsv);
    waitKey(33);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try searching online before posting here. Looking briefly I found this page that explains color detection in OpenCV: http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html

Comment: Thanks! I had already looked into that website and couldn't understand anything but finally after some more reading I was able to understand the code given in that website.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in three steps:

1. Load frame.
2. Convert BGR to HSV color space.
3. [Inrange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) between the color range to detect.

**Edit**

You can use this [code](http://pastebin.com/EHz2a0YP) to find the HSV value of any pixel from your source image. You can see a good explanation about HSV color space [here](http://www.shervinemami.info/colorConversion.html), download the HSV colour wheel from there and manually find out the HSV range.

The following range can be used for the image supplied in [the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvGMz.jpg):

```
hsv_min--> (106,60,90)
hsv_max-->(124,255,255)
```

The following code can be used:

```
Mat src=imread("image.jpg");
Mat HSV;
Mat threshold;
    
cvtColor(src,HSV,CV_BGR2HSV);
inRange(HSV,Scalar(106,60,90),Scalar(124,255,255),threshold);
imshow("thr",threshold);
```

This is the input:

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: I have a question. I can convert to HSV but how exactly do I find the "inRange" for my color which may vary over an image slightly.
Take a look at this image:  
http://i.stack.imgur.com/0xud4.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it always hit and trial? How can we say a certain color lies between a range. For example I was using something like (3,50,50) and (19,240,240) as my  range.
But it would miss a few markers. When I changed the initial range to (3,70,50) some more markers were detected but some earlier ones vanished. I really can't grasp the concept.

Comment: Btw I just changed the range in my program and the range you mention did not function in my program at all.

Comment: Well my fault it seems. It works perfectly on the image you used.
But have a look at these:
http://sdrv.ms/17bFUnr
There are three more similar photos there one of which I sampled using the color range u mentioned and it gave good results but not perfect.
Problem is I am sampling a video and in some images I get all 65 markers sampled but in some images I get only 64.